# display data from 2 joined tables in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables,and i am performing a left join on them,i want the resultant table to be displayed in my View, any ideas how to do that?

This is my controller section

```
public Actionresult display()
{
    var joindata = (from c in dd.CategoryTbls join n in dd.SubCategoryTbls on c.Id equals n.CategoryId select new { ID=c.Id,CategoryName= c.CategoryName,SubCategoryName=n.SubCategoryName }).ToList();    
    return(joindata);
}
```

I cannot display it as a strongly typed view as the resultant table is join of two tables, so any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Based on @Henk Holterman solution, if you are new to MVC, please take a look at MVC scaffolding to start with.

Comment: I would read up more on MVC and on the concept of viewmodels before you go down this path. It will save you a lot of headache in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want the resultant table to be displayed in my View

That's the wrong approach.

In MVC your views do not show 'a table' but they show 'a model'.

That change in wording is the solution: create a class for your joined records and create a strongly-typed View for that Model.

Comment: Got it,thanks for the solution,any other alternatives??

Comment: What more do you need? You are using MVC, this is a very common application of that pattern. Just follow the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use ViewBag

so instead of passing model to the view do this.

```
ViewBag.Joindata = (from c in dd.CategoryTbls join n in dd.SubCategoryTbls on c.Id equals n.CategoryId select new { ID=c.Id,CategoryName= c.CategoryName,SubCategoryName=n.SubCategoryName }).ToList();
```

You will then be able to access ViewBag from the view **this is very dirty solution.**
Example

```
@ViewBag.Joindata[0].ID
```

will contain first record.

Other option would be instead of using `dynamic` object to create model that does represent your viewModel and use strongly typed view, this would be more appropriate solution to your problem.

```
   public class ThatSpecificViewModel
{
    public ThatSpecificViewModel(int id, string categoryName, string subCategoryName) 
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.CategoryName = categoryName;
        this.SubCategoryName = subCategoryName;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

and select it this way

```
var joindata = (from c in dd.CategoryTbls join n in dd.SubCategoryTbls on c.Id equals n.CategoryId select new ThatSpecificViewModel(c.Id,c.CategoryName,n.SubCategoryName )).ToList();
```

Comment: Best practice is to avoid ViewBag as much as possible, it certainly shouldn't be used for the 'main' data.

Answer (score 0):

All you want is a View model..Make a class like `ViewModelResult` or anything like that

```
public class ViewModelResult    
{      
    public YourTable1 YourTable1{get;set;}      
    public YourTable1 YourTable2 {get;set;}      
}
```

and then make youir code as below :-

```
public Actionresult display()
{
ViewModelResult  joindata = (from c in dd.CategoryTbls join n in dd.SubCategoryTbls on c.Id equals n.CategoryId select new ViewModelResult  { ID=c.Id,CategoryName= c.CategoryName,SubCategoryName=n.SubCategoryName }).ToList();

return view(joindata);
}
```

and in your view bind `ViewModelResult`  as model and there you can perform whatever you want to like showing data in grid via foreach and etc.